# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects(cant sum)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner. I just want to ask why i got an error while displaying error in the output.Any Suggestion?Any help much appreciated.Below is my code.

```
class Player:
  def getchips(self):
      return self.chips
  def setchips(self, add):
      self.chips = self.chips + add

class result():
      if totalplayer > opponenttotal:
          print "You have " + str(totalplayer)
          print self.opponent.getname() + " has " + str(opponenttotal)
          print "You win!"
          self.humanplayer.setchips(bet*2)
          self.humanplayer.setscore()
          self.replay()
class Game:
   def __init__(self):
      self.deck = Deck()
      self.humanplayer = Player()
```

OUTPUT:

> self.chips = self.chips + add TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and
>   'int' objects

Comment: try with: `self.chips = self.chips + str(add)`

Comment: Thank you for your help but when i change add to str(add) it give me these following error---> Output: self.chips = self.chips + str(add)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You do not show where you are setting `self.chips`.  Do you expect this value to be a string or a number?

Comment: Learn more about creating [MCVE]. Your code snippet is nowhere near _complete_ example.

Comment: Its okay now,I already solve the solution. thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is almost certainly that you're accidentally setting `self.chips` to a string, maybe `self.chips = "100"`, when what you probably want is `self.chips = 100`.

Unless you post your complete code, we can only guess.

If that's not the case, then

```
self.humanplayer.setchips(bet*2)
```

which then results in the error you get on

```
self.chips = self.chips + add
```

if `bet` is a string, which is the default result of `input("Place your bet")`, then `bet * 2` is still a string, and then `self.chips + add` is adding a string to your chips, which makes no sense.

Where ever you get bet from, you need to convert it to int via `int()`.